# How should we clean up the [kickstarter] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

We have a [kickstarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kickstarter) tag. The Tag Wiki says "A funding platform for creative projects" (referring to [kickstarter.com](https://www.kickstarter.com/)). Unfortunately... the tag isn't always used that way. It is being used for these things, and possibly more:

- The crowdfunding website (called Kickstarter), as mentioned in the Tag Wiki
- [Kickstart, a way to script system installation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kickstart_(Linux))
- [Google Kick Start](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/), the coding competition

So, what should we do with the [kickstarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kickstarter) tag? Having it refer to multiple (unrelated) things isn't ideal, but with 40 questions, cleaning it up is totally do-able

Comment: [Kick start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kick_start_(disambiguation)#Technology) is a heavily overloaded term.

Comment: `[kickstarter]` the burnination process?

Comment: I'd say that none of the things are really on-topic and warrant a tag, so I'd vote to get rid of the tag altogether.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybcxIpb-R_0

Answer (score 17):

I agree with your suggestion for Google Kick Start, it doesn't need a tag. Ditto for Kickstarter, which AFAIK doesn't offer any public APIs to work with. However, we don't want a tag for Kickstart, as it's entirely a system administration matter.

A Kickstart file is simply a definition list that takes the place of running the default interactive installer, and is typically used to automate installs by system administrators. The only way programming gets involved is that it allows administrators to run pre-install and post-install scripts. These are free-form and can be written in any language that the target system has an interpreter for.

With very few exceptions, the Kickstart environment is the same as what a user would normally encounter when scripting in the given language, so there is no need for a dedicated tag. Having one is likely to attract off-topic questions.

---

For the curious, a typical KS file will look something like this:

```
auth --enableshadow --passalgo="sha512"
install
url --url="http://rainicorn.xxx.internal/repo/scientific/7x/x86_64/os"
eula --agreed
repo --name="mariadb" --baseurl=https://yum.mariadb.org/10.2/rhel7-amd64/
cmdline
firstboot --disable
ignoredisk --only-use=sda
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts=''
lang en_US.UTF-8

network  --bootproto=static --device=eth0 --ip=192.168.242.205 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --nodns --activate --hostname host.xxx.internal
reboot
rootpw --iscrypted $6$d+/e+p5t$YA9q1XnhmBEen0HLsS2S.tznp2LnnALyzReYHn4.Jozvt1Tv3vZ9ePm3/Hew6t67OQDaAlttTWGANnMDa/
user --name=admin --password=$6$rBFVKatD$5PGDCE1VaVs1cEN93sAp66AkYTSyfK940/2wMiITJW6M9mfuZaR5vz6Be8fDJfy/H/z7NLDSmu9bBgHwj. --iscrypted
selinux --enforcing
skipx
timezone America/Toronto
bootloader --append="rhgb vga=788 crashkernel=auto" --location=mbr --driveorder="sda" --boot-drive=sda
zerombr
clearpart --all --drives=sda
part pv.105 --fstype="lvmpv" --size=40459
part /boot --fstype="xfs" --size=500
volgroup vg_pofp --pesize=4096 pv.105
logvol /  --fstype="xfs" --size=8192 --name=lv_root --vgname=vg_xxx
logvol /var  --fstype="xfs" --grow --size=8192 --name=lv_var --vgname=vg_xxx
logvol swap  --fstype="swap" --size=4095 --name=lv_swap --vgname=vg_xxx

%packages
gcc
git
mariadb
%end

%post --interpreter=/bin/bash
echo "Doing post-install tasks..."
/usr/local/bin/firstrun --some-flag --or-other
rm -f /usr/local/bin/firstrun
%end
```

Comment: Part of me agrees with you and part of me wonders if creating a tag would be a good place to put a note that sysadmin questions are off-topic...and also prevent the existing mistagging that's currently happening.  On the other hand, we could also just modify the current [kickstarter] excerpt to point out that it's *not* Kickstart.</musing>

Comment: @RyanM I don't really have an opinion there, although given that people mis-tagging don't seem to be reading the wikis, if that is what we do (I haven't heard of the Kickstart tool before today, and I fully believe miken32 if it is off-topic), it might be better to make a full tag-warning, given that this was largely caused by people not reading the tag wiki

Comment: @cocomac There's probably too few questions here to bother with a tag warning.  Currently they're a bunch of effort and require dev work.

Comment: @RyanM I think the Venn diagram of people who post off-topic questions and the people who read tag wikis looks like this: O O

Comment: @miken32 ...yeah, fair point.  It might at least stop the mistagging, but I guess at least they're currently easy to find?

Comment: @RyanM and miken32: Putting some guidance in the tag excerpt could be useful for other people dealing with questions that shouldn't have been posted, or shouldn't have been tagged that.  But I guess having a tag that only exists to be removed from questions is worse than having no tags of that name, so low-rep users couldn't create it in the first place.  OTOH, if someone does post a question about a Kickstart file, having no tag is unlikely to deter them or make them consider asking on serverfault.com.  But the downside is having it mis-tagged for other things named `kick.*start.*`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding those three subjects, I think

- The [kickstarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kickstarter) tag should be removed from any questions about Google Kick Start, and I don't think that should get its own tag (other programming challenge website tags have been burninated, and I don't think asking about the thing itself is on-topic anyways). Chances are it would just be used on questions where the code is solving a Google Kick Start challenge, and so it doesn't belong as a tag in that case
- We should make a new tag called [kickstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kickstart) to refer to the automation tool (and give it a tag wiki, too). I *think* that is on-topic, as it is scripting and (in terms of on-topic-ness), I'd consider it similar to AutoHotKey (a scripting language to automate other things)
- For the Kickstarter tag, we should keep it as-is. They don't have a public API AFAIK, so making a [kickstarter-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kickstarter-api) tag doesn't make sense here

Comment: Why should we keep [tag:kickstarter] at all? If it's a fundraising platform without an API, what meaning does it add to a programming question? About as much as [tag:apple] I'd say, i.e. nothing useful.

Comment: @Adriaan I think you’re right. I’m not going to delete this answer, but I do think what you miken32 said is correct, though.